# Siri: "Play all songs shuffled" in iOS 10

Tags: siri, ios, music.app

If I am currently playing a song (unshuffled) and use Siri to "Play all songs shuffled", Music continues playing the same song even though Siri is showing that "Shuffle" is considered on. Tapping Next does nothing. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Just try telling siri "shuffle songs" and see if that works.

Comment: Exact same behavior.

Comment: That's strange because i just tell siri 'shuffle songs' and it does it without any other input by me.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, odd, I always tell Siri to "play my music" and it starts to play my library shuffled, works eventhough I'm playing one track on repeat (one track from one album).

I always have shuffle on, you can try that!